# How to href an eps file in the field author of article template

Tags: graphics, hyperref, titles, lncs

I want to include an href to an ORCID id using the ORCID symbol as an EPS file.
This is my code (using `llncs`):

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\title{My title}
%\author{Author Name {\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{ORCID}}}
\author{Author Name {\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{orcid.eps}}}}
\institute{My Institute}
\maketitle
\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{orcid.eps}}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

The commented `\author` line works but when I change the text ORCID by `\includegraphics[scale=1]{orcid.eps}` it doesn't work. There is no problem with the eps file since it appears in pdf after `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\title{<title>}` and `\author{<author>}` under [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperred) also adds `<title>` and `<author>` to the PDF properties, and these properties can't be format-rich. Instead, use `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF string>}` to discern between elements that will be typeset in the output PDF (identified by `<TeX>`) and what makes its way into the PDF properties (identified by `<PDF string>`).

Additionally, some commands need to be `\protect`ed when used in moving arguments, like `\includegraphics`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}% https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines

\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{Author Name\texorpdfstring{ \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}}}{}}
\institute{My Institute}

\maketitle

\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4221-7622}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}
Some text.

\end{document}
```